# Predicted 90% chances with 70% accuracy - so what are the chances?

Tags: probability

If my model, for some inputs, tells me that there is a probability of 90% for an event A to happen but the model predictions agrees with test data in 70% of cases then what is the real probability for event A / what else do I have to know or calculate to get the real probability for an event A?

Update:
I've been asked to give more details.
I have a relation [i1,i2,...,in] -> {0,1}
where in - value of n-th indicator.

I have create a logistic model using neural network.
We can say that this model have "learned" probabilities for the input vector.

I consider the output value of this model to be my probability.

Now, for simplicity of this example, I assume that values >= 0.5 are rounded to 1 and <0.5 are rounded to 0.

Now i take a test data-set and pass it through the model making predictions which I round to 0 or 1. I compare that with real outcomes from the dataset.
The outcomes predicted from the model match the outcomes listed in the test data set in 70% of cases.

What can I do now to correct my probability estimation by the accuracy of prediction? What refining techniques are possible?

Comment: What does "agrees with test data" mean? Exactly the same? Or just close to it? Even with a definition I don't think you can deduce the real probability from this information.. What is the observed probability of A? .

Comment: You need to clarify the situation you're talking about. Are you referring to coverage of confidence intervals, or something else? Please describe in detail rather than in vague generalities.

Comment: @Glen_b: I did edited the answer.